# Square API truncating price?

Tags: node.js, square-connect

I am using the square-connect library, and when creating an item, my price is being truncated. For instance, if I set my item price to be 123.13, what comes out is 1.23.

Here is an example of my code:

```
squareRouter.post('/item', function(req, res){
var item = req.body.item;
console.log(item);
square.api('/me/items', 'POST', item, function(err, resp){
    data_handler(err, resp, res);
  });
});
```

in the console window, here is my item object:

```
{ variations: { 
    pricing_type: 'FIXED_PRICING',
    price_money: { currency_code: 'USD', amount: 123.13 },
    name: 'Small' },
name: 'The Real test',
description: 'The price of this should be $123.13',
visibility: true,
available_online: true,
available_for_pickup: true }
```

but in my dashboard, [image]

I am using the square-connect npm module available here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/square-connect

I have the ugly feeling this is a bug in the npm module, not something I'm doing, but I've very very rarely found this to be true in practice. Am I missing something here, or do I need to find the violating code in the library and fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Square API docs](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/#createitem) indicate that when `currency_code` is `USD`, then `amount` is the number of cents, not the number of dollars. So you should use `12313` instead of `123.13`.

Their sample code for $4.00 uses `400` for `amount`, for example.

```
  "variations": [
    {
      "name": "Small",
      "pricing_type": "FIXED_PRICING",
      "price_money": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "amount": 400
      }
    }
  ]
```

Comment: That's very strange considering they specify the unit as United State **Dollars**. It should really be USC.

Comment: The API uses a number of cents to avoid rounding errors that can occur when working with floating point numbers. This is actually a fairly common practice in financial software.